# Java get sub content from ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, swt

it's very complicated. I'm building a GUI that will take a text file and when I press the "Start" button it will start the "BufferReader" function to read all lines from the file into an ArrayList called "list". After that, I need to catch all Strings from the Array "list" that starts with the letters "CE-", then use the next indexes of the Array "list" until the code gets again a string that starts with "CE-" letters. All strings between the "CE-" need to be added to a new ArrayList called "CE".

- all strings that starts with "CE-" letters are titles.
- all strings that between the indexes that contain "CE-" are my parameters.
- the file contains another titles, not only "CE-"

Here is small part of text file:

```
CE-system-components-accessmanager:
   Access control enable                             ,disabled
   Access policy prototyping                         ,enabled
   Access user group                                 ,enabled
   Implicit roles access policy                      ,disabled
   World access policy                               ,disabled

CE-system-components-eqlog:
   EquipmentLog Enable                               ,false

CE-system-components-eventlog:
   Eventlog Enable                                   ,false
```

and here is the part of code that need to get strings in the indexes between the "CE-" :

```
            for(String s : list) {
                if(s.contains("CE-")){
                    int idx = (list.indexOf(s))+1;
                    String txt = list.get(idx);
                    System.out.println(txt);
                    CE.add(txt);
                }
            }          
            System.out.println(CE);
```

my output from this piece of code it only the first parameter.

```
 Access control enable                             ,disabled
 EquipmentLog Enable                               ,false
 Eventlog Enable                                   ,false
```

My question is how to get all parameters? I've tried some codes but it's won't work.

Comment: And the question?

Comment: `if(s.contains("CE-"))` is only executed on every "title" line. From there you only tke the very next line, but not all lines until the next "title"

Comment: editted, read again please

Comment: If you don't care about the titles at all and you can ensure that any of the "parameters" doesn't start with `CE`, then you can just add every line to your `CE`-list, that is not empty and does not start with `CE-`

Comment: I must use it because the text file contains another titles..

Comment: In that case you need a nested loop that starts at `list.indexOf(s)+1` and goes on until you reach the next line that starts with `CE-`

Comment: I dont know how to do the loop go until it reach line that starts again with "CE-"

Comment: `for(int i = list.indexOf(s)+1;;i++){if(list.get(i).startsWith("CE-"))break;}`

Comment: its not work well, I guess I need more from only this :(

Comment: How is this an 'SWT' question? There is no SWT code in the question.

Comment: @greg-449 because I'm working on GUI in SWT

Comment: That is irrelevant, you only include the SWT tag if your question actually involves SWT code. This is just a plain Java question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses a boolean `inCE` to track if the line in the CE block. It is set true when a 'CE-' line is seen, and set false when a blank line is seen.

```
boolean inCE = false;

for (String line : lines) {
   if (line.contains("CE-")) {
     inCE = true;
   }
   else if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
     inCE = false;
   }
   else if (inCE) {
     System.out.println(line);
     CE.add(line);
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow great, that's working! Can you please explain how the code knows to drop one line and to refer to the parameter at the point where encountering "CE-"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but the code starts with `inCE` set to false so all lines will be discarded until 'CE-' is seen.

Comment: I don't understand what is the role of "inCE" and how does it effects the "line drooping"?

Comment: `inCE` is set to true when the 'CE-' line is seen and set to false when a blank line is seen. For any other line if `inCE` is true the line is one we want.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a genius.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a function to check with a String start with another string.

```
startsWith (start, string) {
 for (let i = 0; i < start.length; i++)
  if (start[i] !== string[i])
    return false

 return true
}
```

Do this for every line, when you reach an "CE-" line start adding lines to your array. 
You also need to know which char element comes at the beginning of the parameters. For me it looks like a tab '\t'.

```
addLines (strArray) {
  let start = "CE-"
  let paramStart = '\t'
  let resultArr = []
  let addMode = false

  for (let i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    if (addMode) {
     if (paramStart === strArray[i][0]) // Check if its a Param line
       resultArr.push(strArray[i])
     else
       addMode = false //Means that you found a new Title, but you still 
                       dont know
                       // if it is a "CE-"
    }

     if(!addMode) // Prevent that you check for Titles when adding param
      if (startsWith(start, strArray[i])) 
       addMode = true                     
  }

  return resultArr
}
```

The `if(addMode)` and `if(!addMode)`, might look bad, but you still need them. When you are adding params you don't know when the next title will appear, so you still need to check that line in the same interaction. That's why it is not an `if else` statement

I guess this is it. I didn't test it, but even if it is not perfect, I guess it could point you in the right direction. Sorry, I did everything in **Javascript** but you get the idea. :P

Comment: btw, there is already a method: `str.startsWith("some String");`

Comment: @greg-449 At the end he says that's written in **Javascript**